# hyperledger composer import identity optsmspid error

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have been able to set up a Google VPC with a Fabric topology of single org with two peers, all on different VM. I have Hyperledger composer on a separate VM and  I am able to create a card with this connection profile

```
{
    "name": "hlfv1",
    "x-type": "hlfv1",
    "x-commitTimeout": 300,
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "client": {
        "organization": "Org0",
        "connection": {
            "timeout": {
                "peer": {
                    "endorser": "300",
                    "eventHub": "300",
                    "eventReg": "300"
                },
                "orderer": "300"
            }
        }
    },
    "channels": {
        "OneOrgsChannel": {
            "orderers": [
                "ordererorg0"
            ],
            "peers": {
                "peer0.org0": {
                    "endorsingPeer": true,
                    "chaincodeQuery": true,
                    "ledgerQuery": true,
                    "eventSource": true
                },
                "peer1.org0": {
                    "endorsingPeer": true,
                    "chaincodeQuery": true,
                    "ledgerQuery": true,
                    "eventSource": true
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "organizations": {
        "Org0": {
            "mspid": "Org0MSP",
            "peers": [
                "peer0.org0",
                "peer1.org0"

            ],
            "certificateAuthorities": [
                "ca.org0"
            ]
        }
    },
    "orderers": {
        "ordererorg0": {
            "url": "grpc://orderer0:7050"
        }
    },
    "peers": {
        "peer0.org0": {
            "url": "grpc://peer0:7051",
            "eventUrl": "grpc://peer0:7053"
        },
        "peer1.org0": {
            "url": "grpc://peer1:7051",
            "eventUrl": "grpc://peer1:7053"
        }

    },
    "certificateAuthorities": {
        "ca.org0": {
            "url": "http://35.200.195.193:7054",
            "caName": "ca.org0"
        }
    }
}
```

While, I am using composer card import I am getting error like this:

> Failed to import Identity Error: Client.createUser Parameter 'opts
>   mspid' required.

I have  hfc-key-store   populated  with  the certificates  of  admin that  fabric  peers  and orderers  uses.

I have searched a lot what is this error, but it seems to be abstract.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have this problem (or maybe others have) just remember to make sure you didn't make a typo in connection.json file. You always mention organisations in two places there: `client` section and `organizations`. Make sure those names are the same.